# How to use Code-first to connect to existing SQL Server CE database?

Tags: ef-code-first, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-ce-4

I want to try using code first to connect to an existing SQL Server Compact Edition database, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620). The tutorial however shows how to connect to a SQL Server or LocalDb.

The main problem is that I cannot add SQL Server Compact data connections from within Server Explorer:

[image]

The EF Powertools use this dialog to connect to the database to be reverse engineered.

I have tried re-installing SQL Server Compact 4 SP1, but that has not helped. Is there any way to install support for SQL Server CE 4 in Visual Studio 2013, or to otherwise generate code first classes from a `.sdf` database file without using powertools?

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363374/is-sql-server-compact-discontinued-from-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a way to integrate it in VS 2013 at the moment but I came accross an article that may help.

[Is/will there be support for SQL Server Compact in Visual Studio 2013?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/01affda9-d4a7-4286-a826-43bfacce3f9e/iswill-there-be-support-for-sql-server-compact-in-visual-studio-2013?forum=sqlce)

It looks like there is a toolbox that can be used to set up your connection strings and design / modify your tables and so fourth. 
I've even found that you can create LINQ to SQL. You may also convert Primary Database files to Compact edition DB files as well.

Here is a direct link...

[SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1)