# Local database cache template visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I can't locate "Local Database Cache template" in visual studio 2013. And I need it.

In Visual Studio 2010, my steps are:

> I have a WPF project, by right-clicking the project node and choosing `Add | New Item`. Under the language, click Data and select the `Local Database Cache template`. Name this `NorthwindLocalDataCache.sync` and click Add. This opens the Configure Data Synchronization screen.

Now in VS 2013, is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 3):

[SQL Server Compact Edition has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20364011/736079)... As such the Local Database Cache, which makes use of that product is no longer part of Visual Studio 2013.

Instead you should now make use of [SQL Server LocalDB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/02/26/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition.aspx) or a Service-based database.

From the Release Notes of Visual Studio 2013:

> ### Local Database Cache
>
> The Local Database Cache template and the Configure Data Synchronization dialog box are not included in Visual Studio 2013. You can use Visual Studio 2013 to open and run projects that were created in Visual Studio 2010 if Microsoft Synchronization Services v1.0 is installed, but if you want to update them in Visual Studio 2013, you must make all changes manually in code. As an alternative, you can continue to use Visual Studio 2010 to maintain and update these projects. For new development, target the new synchronization model that's provided by the Microsoft Sync Framework. For information, see [Microsoft Sync Framework Developer Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default)
>
> <sup>Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx</sup>

As you can see, you're trying to follow a technique that is no longer supported. either upgrade it to the new Sync Framework or manually setup your syncs.

Comment: Please see my edited, I am okay with SQL Server LocalDB. How to apply it to my case?