# IDENTITY_INSERT and SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

The script below creates a table, temporarily turns off auto identity, inserts records whilst specifying the PK value, then re-enables auto identity.

```
DROP TABLE Foo;
GO

CREATE TABLE Foo (Id int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL, 
                  Bar nvarchar(100) NOT NULL);
GO

ALTER TABLE Foo ADD CONSTRAINT FooConstraint PRIMARY KEY (Id);
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Foo ON;
GO

INSERT INTO Foo(Id, Bar) VALUES (1, 'a');
GO
INSERT INTO Foo(Id, Bar) VALUES (2, 'b');
GO
INSERT INTO Foo(Id, Bar) VALUES (3, 'c');
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Foo OFF;
GO

INSERT INTO Foo(Bar) VALUES ('d');
GO
```

Problem is that last insert - it complains that

> A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = Foo,Constraint name = FooConstraint ]

This is unexpected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't get too cozy with Compact; [it has been deprecated and there are better options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20364011/61305).

Comment: @AaronBertrand We still use it, and will continue to do so because it's very convenient. The db is just a file, which I can copy around. I am sure MS will restart support in some fashion, as it makes no sense to not have an in-process/single-file db engine for their platform. If it dies completely at some point, we'll just move to SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the seed like this

```
ALTER TABLE [Foo] ALTER COLUMN [Id] IDENTITY (4, 1)
```

Comment: Tried this in your CE toolbox app - which is excellent! - and it works. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome - If you like my tools, I would be very greateful for a review here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1/view/Reviews

Comment: Review submitted! :-)

Comment: Thanks, very much appreciated!