# Which serverless databases support EF code first migrations?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sqlite

Doese somebody know a good list/rescource, where I can read, which serverless database systems support Entity Framework 6.x and EF code first migrations, including automatic creation of databases and code first migrations?

The goal of this question is to offer customers an alternative to MsSQL, but with minimum changes to the code.

The dream would be, only to change the 'connection string' to point to a serverless database and the application would run as expected. (just the normal MsSQL behavior, but serverless)

For example, some serverless DBs, like SQLite, doesn't seem to support the automatic creation of databases, if they don't exist at application start.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Microsoft has deprecated MS SQL Server Compact from Visual Studio 2013. **My own explanation** for this is, that CE is a serverless DB system, that **only runs on Windows machines today**. Microsofts long term goal seems to be, to offer a real cross platform environment with newer Visual Studio versions. So a serverless DB, that doesn't run on Linux, Android and iOS makes no more sense.

**So maybe the better question would be, which serverless DB supports all major plattforms today and in the future?**

Comment: Have a look at dotConnect: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/

Comment: Try SQL Server CE (compact edition). It's an in-process DB and EF supports it very well.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't right, that SQL Server CE is discontinued, at least from Visual Studio 2013. I see, CE is still there, but I am asking myself: "Is that the future, if Microsoft kicks a DB system from VS, that was supported before?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363374/is-sql-server-compact-discontinued-from-visual-studio-2013

Comment: http://erikej.blogspot.de/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html