# Is it possible to connect to an mdf file without using a server installation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014-express

As stated in my question, I want to know if it is possible to connect a C# application with a `.mdf` file without a Microsoft SQL Server installation.

[I found this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142).

But it looks a little "old" due the fact that it was created for Visual Studio 2010.

Is there another possibility?

I programmed the Application in C# and I create the initial database with Visual Studio 2013 and Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express.

What I have tried:

- Tried the LocalDB (Works but it is still something I have to install on each computer)

Comment: That's like expecting asp.net website to run on IIS without installing .NET framework.

Comment: SQL Server CE is deprecated after VS 2013 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363374/is-sql-server-compact-discontinued-from-visual-studio-2013

Comment: Try SQLite https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1800520/sqlite-datasource-not-available-in-vs-2015

Comment: @NikhilVartak Can you not read/write XLS files in .NET without having MS Office installed?  All you need is drivers. This question should (should?) be treated the same way.

Comment: @PaulZahra SQLite did the trick for me. Thanks! If you create an answer I will accept it.

Comment: May I ask why the question is "On hold"? There are several answers yes, but on nearly all questions there are several answers. A good answer is to long? The comment from "Paul Zahra" is exactly the answer I was searching for, so where is it to long? And how can i improve the question? I don't understand why it is "On Hold". If I am wrong than ok but please explain

Answer (score 3):

In brief: **NO**

`.mdf` is a **SQL Server** file, and as such it **must have** some form of SQL Server (LocalDB, Express, any other edition) installed to be used.

If you need an "embedded" database that can run *without* any server installation, you need to look at SQL Server CE (Compact Edition) with a `.sdf` file, or at something totally different like SQLite.

Comment: Or use [VistaDB](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/vistadb) (slower but to a large degree compatible with SQL Server features).

Comment: By the way... VistaDB is compatible with Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013 but not 2015 it seems.